# how can i change the topic name in index.js with username of users in android firebase CLI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application in which I require to send the push notification to the users. Lets assume there are two users user A and user B if user a follow the user B then he subscribed to the topic which is equal to the username of the user A so when user A uploads something to the firebase then the User B should get the notification about it. I am using Firebase CLI and created the fcm but in
index.js I have to add the topic (eg. return `admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);`) so how can I change  the topic 'notification ' with users username.
Note : there are many users so i want that when user install application then the topic changes to his username in index.js.

Comment: The Firebase command line tools have no way to send FCM messages. It's going to be hard to help without seeing the [minimal complete code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is by far the most efficient way to get help with code-related problems.

Comment: I haven't  stucked in  code  i just need a way to change the topic name with every users username in index.js